# .validator('update') not working for dynamically added fields

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrapvalidator-1000hz

I am using **Bootstrap (plugin): validator.js v0.11.9** [bootstrap validator](https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator) for field validations in a Python project **(Python version 3.6 and Django version 1.11)**. On a button `click` I have added couple of fields to the form using jquery -

**JQuery :**

```
 $("#button1Id").click(function(){
    $("#divInsideFormId").append('filed1-selectoption, field2-datepicker, field3-textbox');             
});
```

According to the docs [validator fields](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-fields)

By default, the validator will only validate fields that are present when the plugin is initialized. If your form has a dynamic set of fields, you will need to call **`$(...).validator('update')`** to inform the plugin that the set of fields to be validated has changed.

I tried the following -

```
$("#button1Id").click(function(){
    $("#divInsideFormId").append('filed1-selectoption, field2-datepicker, field3-textbox');
    $("#formId").validator('update');           
});
```

This did not work. I also tried - `$("#divInsideFormId").append(...).validator('update');`

Even this isn't working.

Can anyone suggest what's wrong with my code or if I am missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a working snippet:

```js
$("#button1Id").click(function(){

    var html = '<label for="inputName" class="control-label">New numeric field</label><input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputNum" placeholder="new num field" required>';
    $("#divInsideFormId").append(html);
    $("#formId").validator('update');           
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.min.js"></script>


<form id="formId" data-toggle="validator" role="form">
  <div id="divInsideFormId" class="form-group">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputName" class="control-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Cina Saffary" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="inputTwitter" class="control-label">Twitter</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
      <input type="text" pattern="^[_A-z0-9]{1,}$" maxlength="15" class="form-control" id="inputTwitter" placeholder="1000hz" required>
    </div>
    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <div class="help-block with-errors">Hey look, this one has feedback icons!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" data-error="Bruh, that email address is invalid" required>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="form-inline row">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <input type="password" data-minlength="6" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" required>
        <div class="help-block">Minimum of 6 characters</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPasswordConfirm" data-match="#inputPassword" data-match-error="Whoops, these don't match" placeholder="Confirm" required>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="underwear" required>
        Boxers
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="underwear" required>
        Briefs
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="terms" data-error="Before you wreck yourself" required>
        Check yourself
      </label>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    <button id="button1Id" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Add field</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

or an equivalent jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/m90m178s/